# how to test search accuracy in solr

Tags: apache, solr, lucene, full-text-search, information-retrieval

Hello I am new with Solr information retravel system
and I want to add a text file to Solr then search for a word form the file in order to see Solr accuracy in other languages but I am not sure how. I find that there is a UI for search but also don't know how to use it and there is data import handler but it must be in XML, CSV or JSON and I want text file but also if I use it I don't know how to search for a word or sentence

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a basic Apache Lucene/Solr course and a deep dive in the Solr wiki[1].

The getting started especially, should really help you.

Good Luck

[1] https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/solr-tutorial.html